# Android Getting R8 error: Already has a mapping when trying to run UI tests with minified build

Tags: android, proguard, minify, android-r8, instrumented-test

I want to be able to run UI tests on a minified build. However when I run

```
 ./gradlew connectedDebugAndroidTest
```

I get this error:

```
> Task :app:minifyDebugAndroidTestWithR8
R8: 'void zza(com.google.android.gms.common.internal.BaseGmsClient,int,android.os.IInterface)' already has a mapping
```

I tried creating a separate proguard file for the tests:

```
buildTypes {
        debug {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            testProguardFile 'proguard-test.pro'
```

```
# proguard-test.pro:
-include proguard-rules.pro
-keepattributes SourceFile,LineNumberTable
-dontobfuscate
-dontwarn
-dontshrink
```

But that didn't help. Not sure what else to try.

Comment: On which version of Android Studio/AGP do you see this issue? There has been a number of issues fixed in this area, that latest being https://issuetracker.google.com/140851070. Could you perhaps try with the latest Android Studio 4.2 (https://developer.android.com/studio/preview)? You can also just use AGP 4.2.0-rc01 without having to update Android Studio by using this dependency: `com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.0-rc01` in yout top level `build.gradle`file. If that does not fix the issue please file a bug at https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=326788.

Comment: That seems to have fixed it, thanks @sgjesse!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There has been a number of "Already has a mapping" issues (the most recent being issuetracker.google.com/140851070). All known issues of this kind has been fixed for Android Studio 4.2 (currently on preview, developer.android.com/studio/preview).

One can also use AGP 4.2.0-rc01 without having to update Android Studio by using this dependency: `com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.0-rc01` in the top level `build.gradle` file.